# display json data acoording param parameter

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

want to display json data according to the parameter which is catch by state params but problem is that array does not show any thing  , me using  the underscore lib , kindly check the controller and tell me where the problem or any alternative way to do it ..

```
.controller('abCtrl',function($scope,$http,$stateParams) {


$http.get("http://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=<private_key>").then(function (response) {

      $scope.filteredOffers = [];
      var offerName = $stateParams.offer_name;
      $scope.filteredOffers = _.filter(response.data, ["offer_name",offerName]);
    
      console.log($scope.filteredOffers)
      console.log(offerName)
      })


})
```

Comment: do you see data in console?

Comment: console.log($scope.filteredOffers) show empty array while  console.log(offerName) show the offername and response.data also give data .

Comment: can i get team viewer?

Comment: bhatnagarabhi2411@gmail..com send yours will send the code

Comment: just downloaded kindly do come on chat

Comment: i also download the TV we can do it there also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter should be,

```
$scope.filteredOffers = $filter('filter')(response.data, {offer_name: offerName});
```

also inject $filter to your controller,

```
.controller('abCtrl',function($scope,$http,$stateParams,$filter) {
```